# Gatsby - Is it possible to preserve newlines when parsing/displaying content from a YAML file?

Tags: javascript, yaml, gatsby

I currently have some data in a YAML file and I want to be able to preserve the line breaks when it gets converted into HTML using `gatsby-remark-transformer`. For example,

```
summary: > 
    I want this 

    to be displayed on two separate lines.
```

Is there a way to do this? Adding the newline character `\n` and using the block style `|` hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried parsing the `summary` content and replacing the `\n` for `<br/>`?

```
const formattedSummary = summary.split(`\n\n`).map(text => `<p>${text.replace(/\n/g, `<br>`)}</p>`).join(``)
```

Another alternatives are discussed in [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/12568):

- Using [`lines-to-paragraph`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lines-to-paragraphs) package:

  ```
  import paragraphs from "lines-to-paragraphs"

  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: paragraphs(description) }} />
  ```